# Salesforce Deactivating the salesforce users who are not logged in last 3 months using apex program

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

I have written code for deactivating users who are not logged in last 3 months , but when I am running the program , it is giving me an exception like you can't deactivate this user because of the ownership of the records so then it is not checking for other users.

```
public class ExampleUser 
{   

    public static void deactivate()
    {

        List<User> usersToUpdate = new List<User>();


        for(User u: [SELECT Id, IsActive FROM User where IsActive= true and LastLoginDate <= :DATE.TODAY()-90])
        {
            u.IsActive = false;
            /*try {
                update u;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.debug(e);
            }*/
            usersToUpdate.add(u);
        }  
        if (usersToUpdate.size()>0)
        {   
            
            update usersToUpdate; 
        } 
    }
}
```

If I run the commented code(trying to deactivated each user seperately) it is giving an exception with more than 100 SOQL queries.
can anyone please help me in resolving this issue

Answer (score 1):

Use `Database.update(usersToUpdate, false)` to avoid rolling back the entire transaction if one or more records fails.

That doesn't really solve your problem as such; it just means you do deactivate the users that can be deactivated. You'll need to develop a different solution if you want to review the users that cannot be deactivated for any reason.

You don't need to check the list size. Performing DML on an empty list does nothing.